# How can i bind to an input type file field that is created dynamically without an ID. Using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, file-io, bind

So i'm using a joomla component (rsformspro) that produces dynamic input(file type) fields into a html form.

I have a listener which checks the file selected is landscape and below a certain filesize. When the file doesn't meet the requirements. The file value is cleared(value =''). This works.

i also have an add file button. The script won't fire on this button after a new input field has been added to the dom.

i have used jquery on function with change. Which works, as far as my script runs. but the resetting of value doesn't work. i know i'm 99% of the way. just need the last part to reset the current input field field.
html below:

```
<div class="formBody" style="background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="rsfp-field-multiple-plus" style="background-size: cover;"><input type="file" name="form[image_upload_gallery][]" id="image_upload_gallery" data-rsfp-skip-ajax="true" class="rsform-upload-box" data-rsfp-minfiles="1" data-rsfp-maxfiles="20" data-rsfp-exts="[&quot;jpeg&quot;,&quot;jpg&quot;,&quot;png&quot;,&quot;gif&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;]"></div><button type="button" class="rsfp-field-multiple-plus-button" data-rsfp-maxfiles="20" data-rsfp-formid="4" onclick="RSFormPro.addMoreFiles(this);">Add another file</button>
                        <span class="formValidation"><span id="component47" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span></span>
                        <p class="formDescription"></p>
                    <div class="rsfp-field-multiple-plus" style="background-size: cover;"><input type="file" name="form[image_upload_gallery][]" id="image_upload_gallery" data-rsfp-skip-ajax="true" class="rsform-upload-box" data-rsfp-minfiles="1" data-rsfp-maxfiles="20" data-rsfp-exts="[&quot;jpeg&quot;,&quot;jpg&quot;,&quot;png&quot;,&quot;gif&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;]"></div></div>
```

[image of input field "Image upload Gallery"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PGzz.png)

Below is the jquery/javascript:

```
/*testing second image capture for the gallery field */ 
    var file_holder2 = jQuery(".formBody input:file").on('change',function (e) {
        var file, img;
        var widescreen = 16/9; 
        var standard = 4/3;
        
        console.log('image upscript script is active value of file is: '+jQuery('input[type=file]').val());
            if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                //alert('filesize is'+file.size);
                img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                 var userRatio = this.width / this.height;
                 if(userRatio == widescreen && this.width > 600 && file.size < 1002400)//make sure image is 16/9, width less than 600 px & filesize less than 1mb
                 {
                    //all is ok and it can be uploaded.
                 }else{
                    alert("Please make sure your image is:\n 1: Landscape (16:9 ratio).\n 1024px x 768px is recommended (jpeg or PNG)\n 2: No more than 1mb in size.\n 3: Width must be 600px minimum.\n\n Please try again with another image \filename is :"+this.value);
                     //jQuery(this).closest('div').remove();
                     //jQuery(this).hide();
                    //file.value='';
                     file_holder2.val('');
                     //file_holder2.value = '';
                     //jQuery(this).val('');
                    //this.files[0].value='';
                     //this.value=null;
                 }                          
                };
                img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
```

This is inside a doc ready function.

The above script works for the 1st file field. But when a second is added. The script doesn't fire.

When i add a second parameter 'rsform-upload-box' to the on change function like below:

```
var file_holder2 = jQuery(".formBody input:file").on('change','rsform-upload-box',function (e) {
```

Then the script doesn't fire.

So just need to know what i need to make any newly added input value set to null.

Comment: `rsform-upload-box` is not a valid selector - you're missing the class selector prefix: `.rsform-upload-box`. Also the second selector should be a child of the primary, so the user of `input:file` is incorrect. The full line should be: `var file_holder2 = jQuery(".formBody").on('change','.rsform-upload-box',function (e) {`

Comment: *The script won't fire on this button after a new input field has been added to the dom* - your script runs before the element is added.  `$("selector")` only applies to elements that exist when that code runs.  Change `jQuery(".formBody input:file").on('change','rsform-upload-box'` to `jQuery(".formBody").on('change','.rsform-upload-box'`

Comment: On its own, changing to event delegation won't work due to wrong selector/nesting, but you still need event delegation: See [event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)